# Problem about doubly linked list using arrays

Tags: arrays, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

[image]

Hi we began talking about data structures and I'm having trouble coming up with a code for this problem
This is basicaly a 3 arrays implementation of a doubly linked list , P(prev pointer)/N(next pointer)/D(data) but I'm having trouble understaing how I can use the new arrays outside of the fucntion?
I mean from my understanding we are given an array and we are manipulating it but it just confuses me how the new arrays come into play..

Also in the follow up questions, do they mean the complexity complexity or just each operation we need to perform like?
btw it's my first time writing psedueocode, does it look okay?

```
InsertFirst(k)

if (Free ≠ -1) then  
  q = free 
else                         //Create new arrays
  newArray ➜ newD(2n)  
  newArray ➜ newP(2n) 
  newArray ➜ newN(2n)

 for i=0 ➜ n   
     newD[i] = D[i]   
     newP[i] = D[i]   
     newN[i] = D[i]

  newD[q] = k                //Insert first if list is full
  Free = newN[Free]  
  newN[q] = L  
  newP[L] = q  
  L = q  
  return

D[q] = k                //Insert first if list is not full
Free = N[Free] 
N[q] = L 
P[L] = q 
L = q 
return
```

Comment: If you have questions about the meaning of an assignment, should you not ask that to the one who gave the assignment? Also, you are asking multiple questions. A question on Stack Overflow should be one question, and specific. How to use arrays "outside of a function", should be more specific. The code you provided does that... it is not clear what you are asking about that.

Comment: BTW, you are [not the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655404/doubly-linked-list-array-implementation) asking about this assignment.